# Pythons Pandas - conditionally loop columns within dataframe and compare to reference dataset

Tags: python, pandas, csv, conditional-statements

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm a bit new to Python and have limited experience using the panda's library. However, I have been trying to modify the following data frame such that the program takes the contents 3 CSV file, creates two new variables based on the data from the first and second data frames then concatenates them in a var called Pred_arg - this is a reference data frame to which comparisons are made.

The 3rd CSV file is the test results - which are added for the var df.

Following this, I am trying to create a script scan each column of var and return true or false (in an output table) based on the condition that each cluster group has at least one value from ABCPred and BCEPred - the goal then is to print the result out to a summary table with true or false for each cluster - if there is at least 1 True in the cluster results then that cluster is marked true.

My goal is something like:

```
Cluster Number  Status 
clu1            True          
clu2            True
clu3            False
...             ...
clu57           True
```

where I can later use the group by function to the group and count all those that are True, and all those that are False - ultimately I need to delete all rows that return false, but I can do this bit

**What I've done so far**

step 1 - read in results from ABCPred and tidy up

```
ABCPred = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\tonyr\OneDrive - Ulster University\PhD - Stratified medicine research projects\COVID19 paper 2020\Data\Output data\ABCPred_res(254).csv")
ABCPred.columns = ['Seq','drop1','drop2','drop3','drop4']
ABCPred = ABCPred[ABCPred['Seq'].notna()]
ABCPred = ABCPred.drop(columns = ['drop1','drop2','drop3','drop4'])
print(ABCPred)


                      Seq
0        AGAAAYYVGYLQPRTF
1          AGCLIGAEHVNNSY
2        AGTITSGWTFGAGAAL
3    AGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPF
4            ALEPLVDLPIGI
..                    ...
248    YQTQTNSPRRARSVASQS
249    YSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLM
250  YSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDL
251    YTSALLAGTITSGWTFGA
252      YVGYLQPRTFLLKYNE
```

Step 2 - read in results from BCEPred and tidy

```
BCEPred = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\tonyr\OneDrive - Ulster University\PhD - Stratified medicine research projects\COVID19 paper 2020\Data\Output data\BCEPred_res_cor.csv")
print(BCEPred)

            Seq
0       IHVSGTNGT
1        VYFASTEK
2        TTLDSKTQ
3         VYYHKNN
4         MDLEGKQ
5       SYLTPGDSS
6         DPLSETK
7        YAWNRKRI
8         QIAPGQT
9        NNLDSKVG
10       RLFRKSNL
11     ATVCGPKKST
12       GVLTESNK
13      VITPGTNTS
14        RVYSTGS
15  ASYQTQTNSPRRA
16        LPVSMTK
17       ICGDSTEC
18      IAVEQDKNT
19   QILPDPSKPSKR
20       GKIQDSLS
21        TLVKQLS
22      ECVLGQSKR
23        EVAKNLN
24       CKFDEDDS
```

Step 3 - I add these data frames into a new one called Pred_arg

```
Pred_arg = ABCPred.assign(ABCSeq = ABCPred['Seq'],BCEPred = BCEPred['Seq']).reset_index()
Pred_arg = Pred_arg.drop(columns = ['index','Seq'])
print(Pred_arg)

                   ABCSeq    BCEPred
0        AGAAAYYVGYLQPRTF  IHVSGTNGT
1          AGCLIGAEHVNNSY   VYFASTEK
2        AGTITSGWTFGAGAAL   TTLDSKTQ
3    AGTITSGWTFGAGAALQIPF    VYYHKNN
4            ALEPLVDLPIGI    MDLEGKQ
..                    ...        ...
248    YQTQTNSPRRARSVASQS        NaN
249    YSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLM        NaN
250  YSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDL        NaN
251    YTSALLAGTITSGWTFGA        NaN
252      YVGYLQPRTFLLKYNE        NaN
```

So now I have created the reference data frame which i want to compare agaisnt

Step 4 - import test results for comparison

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\tonyr\OneDrive - Ulster University\PhD - Stratified medicine research projects\COVID19 paper 2020\Data\IEDB_dataset_run1.csv")
df = df.drop(columns = ['Alignment','Position','Description'])
df = df.drop(df[df.Peptide == '-'].index) #removes all rows where '-' exsists in the peptide column
df = df.drop(df[df['Peptide Number'] == 'Singleton'].index) #remove singletons

     Cluster Number Peptide Number               Peptide
1                 1              1  QDVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPT
2                 1              2  DVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTW
3                 1              3  EVPVAIHADQLTPTWRVYST
4                 1              4  PVAIHADQLTPTWRVYSTGS
5                 1              5      DQLTPTWRVYSTGSNV
..              ...            ...                   ...
307              55              2    TQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFV
309              56              1      CCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE
310              56              2              CKFDEDDS
312              57              1    CCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFD
313              57              2      CCSCLKGCCSCGSCCK
```

**This is where I am stuck**

I've tried grouping based on clusters from Step 4 which although presents everything nice, where the cluster number is an index going from 0 to 57, I can't use the group to check if ABCPred AND BCEPred isin clu1.

if I try using isin for one condition (i.e. ABCPred results) it all returns false

```
df_groups = df.groupby(["Cluster Number"])["Peptide"].apply(list)
df_groups.columns = ['Cluster Number', 'Seq(s)']
print(df_groups)

Cluster Number
1     [QDVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPT, DVNCTEVPVAIHADQLTPTW, E...
2     [ISVTTEILPVSMTKTSVDCT, EILPVSMTKTSVDCTMYI, ILP...
3     [STEKSNIIRGWIFGTTLD, KSNIIRGWIFGTTLDS, IRGWIFG...
4     [YQPYRVVVLSFELLHAPATV, SFELLHAPATVCGP, FELLHAP...
5     [LHRSYLTPGDSSSG, HRSYLTPGDSSSGWTA, SYLTPGDSSSG...
6     [VYSSANNCTFEYVSQPFL, YSSANNCTFEYVSQPFLMDL, YSS...
7     [QIPFAMQMAYRFNG, PFAMQMAYRFNGIGVT, FAMQMAYRFNG...
8     [ASYQTQTNSPRRA, YQTQTNSPRRARSVASQS, YQTQTNSPRR...
9     [EMIAQYTSALLAGTITSG, YTSALLAGTITSGWTFGA, LAGTI...
10    [TPCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQ, PCSFGGVSVITPGTNTSNQV, P...
11    [RGVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQD, GVYYPDKVFRSSVLHSTQ, KVF...
12    [YNENGTITDAVDCA, NENGTITDAVDCALDP, ENGTITDAVDC...
13    [GVSPTKLNDLCFTNVYADSF, TKLNDLCFTNVYADSFVI, NDL...
14    [GVYYHKNNKSWMESEFRV, VYYHKNNKSWMESEFRVYSS, VYY...
15    [PFGEVFNATRFASVYAWNRK, TRFASVYAWNRKRI, RFASVYA...
16    [AGCLIGAEHVNNSY, GCLIGAEHVNNSYECD, LIGAEHVNNSY...
17    [TEIYQAGSTPCNGVEG, YQAGSTPCNGVEGFNC, QAGSTPCNG...
18    [QQFGRDIADTTDAVRDPQTL, QQFGRDIADTTDAV, QFGRDIA...
19    [YFPLQSYGFQ, LQSYGFQPTNGVGYQP, YGFQPTNGVGYQPYR...
20    [IHVSGTNGTKRFDNPVLPFN, IHVSGTNGT, VSGTNGTKRFDN...
21    [NLREFVFKNIDGYFKIYS, EFVFKNIDGYFKIYSKHT, FKNID...
22    [IAVEQDKNT, AVEQDKNTQEVFAQ, VEQDKNTQEVFAQV, QD...
23    [DKVEAEVQIDRLITGRLQSL, EAEVQIDRLITGRLQSLQTY, Q...
24    [DSLSSTASALGKLQDV, LSSTASALGKLQDVVNQN, LSSTASA...
25    [PGQTGKIADYNYKLPD, GQTGKIADYNYKLP, TGKIADYNYKL...
26    [YEQYIKWPWYIWLGFIAG, YEQYIKWPWYIWLGFI, YIKWPWY...
27    [TVEKGIYQTSNFRVQP, EKGIYQTSNFRVQPTE, KGIYQTSNF...
28    [KSNLKPFERDISTEIYQA, SNLKPFERDISTEIYQAGST, FER...
29     [VLYNSASFSTFKCYGVSP, FSTFKCYGVSPTKL, STFKCYGVSP]
30    [HGVVFLHVTYVPAQEK, GVVFLHVTYVPAQEKNFT, HVTYVPA...
31    [PGTNTSNQVAVLYQDV, GTNTSNQVAVLYQDVNCT, TSNQVAV...
32    [KQIYKTPPIKDFGGFN, KTPPIKDFGGFN, TPPIKDFGGFNFS...
33    [VTQQLIRAAEIRASANLAAT, VTQQLIRAAEIRASANLA, TQQ...
34     [GCVIAWNSNNLDSKVGGNYN, CVIAWNSNNLDSKV, NNLDSKVG]
35         [GNYNYLYRLFRKSNLKPF, NYLYRLFRKSNL, RLFRKSNL]
36    [GGFNFSQILPDPSKPSKR, SQILPDPSKPSKRSFI, QILPDPS...
37    [SSNFGAISSVLNDI, SNFGAISSVLNDILSRLD, ISSVLNDIL...
38      [QKEIDRLNEVAKNLNE, KEIDRLNEVAKNLNESLI, EVAKNLN]
39    [FPNITNLCPFGEVFNA, PNITNLCPFGEVFN, NITNLCPFGEV...
40                           [LTGTGVLTESNKKF, GVLTESNK]
41                           [VLPFNDGVYFASTE, VYFASTEK]
42                   [ECSNLLLQYGSFCTQLNRAL, LQYGSFCTQL]
43                          [EVRQIAPGQTGKIADY, QIAPGQT]
44                       [QLPPAYTNSFTR, PPAYTNSFTRGVYY]
45         [VTLADAGFIKQYGDCLGDIA, GFIKQYGDCLGDIAARDLIC]
46                            [TLVKQLS, LVKQLSSNFGAISS]
47                         [IGKIQDSLSSTASALG, GKIQDSLS]
48             [TNVVIKVCEFQFCNDP, VVIKVCEFQFCNDPFLGVYY]
49               [ESLIDLQELGKYEQYI, DLQELGKYEQYIKWPWYI]
50               [GDIAARDLICAQKFNGLT, RDLICAQKFNGLTVLP]
51                   [PQGFSALEPLVDLPIGIN, ALEPLVDLPIGI]
52               [VVIGIVNNTVYDPLQPEL, VIGIVNNTVYDPLQPE]
53                   [EILDITPCSFGGVSVI, EILDITPCSFGGVS]
54               [NFRVQPTESIVRFPNITN, VQPTESIVRFPNITNL]
55                 [WFVTQRNFYEPQII, TQRNFYEPQIITTDNTFV]
56                         [CCSCGSCCKFDEDDSE, CKFDEDDS]
57               [CCSCLKGCCSCGSCCKFD, CCSCLKGCCSCGSCCK]


rslt_df = Pred_arg['ABCSeq'].isin(df_groups)
print(rslt_df.describe()) ## comparason coming back all false !!!!!!!

count       253
unique        1
top       False
freq        253
Name: ABCSeq, dtype: object
```

I know I'm missing something most likely very simple - but figured some fresh eyes and guidance would be of great help improving my practice.

**update**

I seem to be able to make a comparison between cell contents using the following method - although its pretty crude

```
#comparing group to pred_arg
rslt_df1 = Pred_arg['ABCSeq'].isin(df['Peptide'])
rslt_df2 = Pred_arg['BCEPred'].isin(df['Peptide'])
rslt_df = df.assign(ABCSeq = rslt_df1, BCEPred = rslt_df2).reset_index()
concencus = Pred_arg['ABCSeq'].isin(df['Peptide']) & Pred_arg['BCEPred'].isin(df['Peptide'])

print(concencus.describe()) # working better

count       253
unique        2
top       False
freq        232
dtype: object
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Use https://biopython.org/. It might contain everything that you need.

Comment: @VisheshMangla thank you very much - I've used pyphy briefly in the past, but this biopython is a great resource: I've browse through it over the next few days. So far none of the tools is jumping out except snpFC but I'll take a closer look

Comment: That's great.Enjoy the work and support the library.

Comment: @VisheshMangla Thanks, I must check it out - no worries, I'm an engineer don't have a clue about biology really, except that my PhD is on genomic data analysis (hardware acceleration)

Comment: @VisheshMangla This question would be off-topic on Code Review as it does not work as intended. In the future please link to the help center and use wording that shows the post may be off-topic when recommending Code Review. Take, "This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there."

Comment: Sorry, @Peilonrayz, I should have read it better.Also, I don't remember if I flagged this question. I just suggested that I saw too many biologists on codereview which they can chat with or collaborate.